# Receiving error when executing New-SPSite in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have two web applications in SharePoint 2010 that are both empty (and were created the same way through Central Admin). I have a PowerShell script that creates a new site collection and then automates various other tasks after the site collection is created. I can execute my script successfully in the first web application. Then, when executing the same script on the second web application, the following error is rendered:

```
"The system cannot find the file specified."
```

After some investigation, I have found that this command was breaking:

`New-SPSite -url $newsite -name $newname -template "STS#0"`

The specific error is happening because the site template (STS#0) cannot be found. I have also tried creating the site with different templates, but I get the same error. It is acting as if the second web application cannot find any of the site templates.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Must have been an IIS issue. Rebooted the box and all is well.